# My Typescript-based Angular 2 App Started Compiling Javascript Files Within the App Folder

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

My Angular 2 app uses Typescript, and everything gets compiled down to Javascript files in the "dist" folder. Everything was working as expected, with ts (Typescript) files in my "app" folder and Javascript files in my "dist" folder. Then, for some reason yesterday, my "app" folder started showing the generation of js files right there, whenever I would create a new ts file. Furthermore, all of my existing ts files now show accompanying js files. I didn't change anything to affect this setting, so why is it that I'm getting compiled javascript in my "app" folder now, as well as where it's supposed to go - in the "dist" folder? My Angular 2 app still works, but now I have all these extraneous files in my "app" folder that don't need to be - and shouldn't be - there. How can I resolve this?

BTW, here is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": "./app"
  },
  "files": [
    "app/main.ts",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Check your tsconfig.json file

Comment: I added my tsconfig.json above. Do you see anything problematic?

Comment: Did you changed anything? IDE, using CLI?

Comment: This is not a CLI project. And I haven't changed my IDE (using Visual Studio Code).

Comment: One note: another team member uses a different IDE. But I haven't changed mine.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure this is not caused by a setting in your IDE that can automatically compile typescript. Make some changes in your ts files in the text editor that doesn't support typescript and see if this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks, but if I didn't manually change any settings in my IDE, so I'm unclear why would this suddenly happen now - two months into the project. It hasn't been a problem up until yesterday.